# Adding last cell as button

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview

[image: Here is my CollectionView with cells]

**I need to set last cell as button that can add new cell to this array of cells. here is some my code**

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let category = self.categories[indexPath.row]
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CategoryCollectionViewCell.name, for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell
    cell.label.text = category.name
    return cell
}
private var categories = [Category]()
    private func createCustomCategories() {
    let categoryOne = Category(id: "01", name: "B")
    let categoryTwo = Category(id: "02", name: "Weddings")
    let categoryThree = Category(id: "03", name: "Just want it")
    let addButton = Category(id: "none", name: "+ add")
    self.categories.append(contentsOf: [categoryOne, categoryTwo, categoryThree])
    self.categories.append(addButton)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create both a **`CustomCell`** Class to represent your categories, and another **`ButtonCell`** Class to represent your button,

assuming this is your items array:

> ```
> var items = [1,2,3,4,5]
> ```

**in your dataSource funcs add +1 for your button**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count + 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == items.count {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "\(ButtonCell)", for: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
        } else {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "\ . 
 (YourSelf)", for: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
     }     
 }
```

Comment: I made this but I always get index out of range. Added code to 1st code

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

at `numberOfItemsInSection` `return self.categories.count +1`

And at `cellForRow`:

```
if indexPath.item > categories.count{ //last element of categories array is passed
cell.label.text = "+ add"
}
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add the button with unique ID to categories ?

```
let addButton = Category(id: "UniqueID", name: "+ add")
// append the addButton in category array
self.categories.append(contentsOf: [categoryOne, categoryTwo, categoryThree, addButton])
```

And then just switch on the Id, And also have a separate cell for button.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let category = self.categories[indexPath.row]
    // check for category.id == your uniqueID that you have appended above
    if category.id == "UniqueID" {
      // Make sure you have another collectionViewCell and use its identifier in here
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:AddButtonCell.name, for: indexPath) as! AddButtonCell
        // set the label here
        cell.label.text = category.name
        return cell
    } else {
        // use your original collectionview cell here.
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CategoryCollectionViewCell.name, for: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell
        cell.label.text = category.name
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: well you code is different to mines. and your adding +1 to item count.

Comment: how should I do this "+1" in numbersOfItemsInSection?

Comment: I can understand how can I set my cell with id =="UniqueID" to last in array

Comment: You need to do +1 in numberOfItemsInSection if you don't add to category. My suggestion was add it the Category you have, so you do not need to do +1

Comment: but what code helps me to return cell with id =="UniqueID" to last in array ?

Comment: have a look at my comments in the answer above.

Comment: @ЕвгенийТишкин have you seen the comments?

Answer (score 0):

**I made this but I always get index our of range**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return categories.count + 1
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

       let category = categories[indexPath.item]


       if indexPath.item == categories.count + 1 {
           guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CategoryCollectionViewCell.name, for: indexPath) as? CategoryCollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell.init() }
           cell.setText(text: "add")
           return cell
       } else {
            guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CategoryCollectionViewCell.name, for: indexPath) as? CategoryCollectionViewCell else {return UICollectionViewCell.init()}
            cell.setText(text: category.name!)
            return cell
    }
}
```